# Display Resolution Setting is Lost After Wake from Suspend

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have an AMD Radeon RX 460 Graphics (AMD POLARIS11 / DRM 3.23.0 / 4.15.0-72-generic, LLVM 5.0.1) which is connected to two 4k dell monitors with the latest amdgpu driver. When I wake the computer up from suspend, my display setting is often lost and one of my monitors render in half like below.

[image]

If I log out and log back in, 80% of the time this is fixed but not always.

Here is what the setting looks like

[image]

1. What could be the cause of this?
2. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

From time to time the Window Manager will reset my displays as well. So as to not have to go manually reset them (or reboot) I've created a function in `~/.bashrc` to do this for me:

```bash
xreset () {

    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --primary \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal

} # xreset
```

Whenever the screens are "wacky" I open a terminal and type `xreset`.

The first step for you is to create a similar function. The next step is to have it automatically called when suspending from resume. To do that create a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` and mark it executable.

Of course the desirable solution is to fix the Window Manager (Unity, GDM, etc) but if that isn't possible this band-aid approach can be taken.

Comment: Thank you for the answer however this did not work as it was reporting that my resolution could not be found. I noticed that when this happens one of the monitors is categorized as unknown in the display settings.

Comment: Did you make sure you turned the monitors on and waiting until they displayed "No signal" before resuming?

Comment: oh, for sure. my monitors are on all the time. and I ran the command after I see the distorted display. This happens maybe %30 of the time